# JPA Unit Test Case Delete Operation Wanted but not Invoked

Tags: java, unit-testing, jpa, mockito

I was having some problem when trying to create a junit test cases for delete with JPA. In my service class, I am using the default function provided by JPA:

```
public void delete(Long id) {
        log.debug("Request to delete Enroll : {}", id);
        enrollRepository.deleteById(id);
}
```

Then my unit test, I am trying to mock an object and then perform the deletion:

```
@Test
public void testDeleteEnrollExpectSuccess() {
    Enroll enroll = prepareEnrollWithBedAllocation();
    enrollService.delete(enroll.getId());
    verify(enrollRepository, times(1)).delete(enroll);
}
```

I am tyring to mock the enroll object like this:

```
private Enroll prepareEnrollWithBedAllocation() {
    LocalDateTime localDateTime = LocalDateTime.now();
    ZonedDateTime zonedDateTime = ZonedDateTime.of(localDateTime, ZoneId.of("UTC"));

    Enroll enroll = new Enroll();
    enroll.setId(new Long(1));
    enroll.seteDate(zonedDateTime);
    enroll.setEbStartdt(zonedDateTime);
    enroll.setEbEnddt(zonedDateTime);
    enroll.setBed(prepareBed());
    enroll.setPatient(preparePatient());
    enroll.setDoc(prepareDoc());
    enroll.seteCondition("Normal");
    return enroll;
}
```

However, I am getting these error messages and my test case was failed:

```
Wanted but not invoked:
enrollRepository.delete(
    Enroll{id=1, eCondition='Normal', eRemarks='null', ebStartdt='2019-04-09T16:40:32.703Z[UTC]', ebEnddt='2019-04-09T16:40:32.703Z[UTC]', eDate='2019-04-09T16:40:32.703Z[UTC]'}
);
-> at com.team.generated.service.EnrollServiceTest.testDeleteEnrollExpectSuccess(EnrollServiceTest.java:61)

However, there was exactly 1 interaction with this mock:
enrollRepository.deleteById(1L);
-> at com.team.generated.service.EnrollService.delete(EnrollService.java:74)
```

Any idea? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error says for itself: you're verifing the method `delete(Long id)`:

```
verify(enrollRepository, times(1)).delete(enroll);
```

However, your service object invokes `deleteById()` method:

```
enrollRepository.deleteById(id);
```

I think you want to do this:

```
@Test
public void testDeleteEnrollExpectSuccess() {
    Enroll enroll = prepareEnrollWithBedAllocation();
    enrollService.delete(enroll.getId());
    verify(enrollRepository, times(1)).deleteById(enroll.getId());
}
```

Comment: May I check with you do you have any example for the unit test for update?

Comment: @hyperfkcb, no, but it's done in the same way. Just don't confuse methods being executed.